# Error 403 when sorting on id

Tags: sorting, phpmyadmin, primary-key

With version 4.5.1 of phpMyAdmin,  I get:

```
Error 403 (text : forbidden)
```

when I click on the header of the columns `id` to sort on this column. The error doesn't occur on the other columns or on table where the primary key column is like `meta_id` or `table_id`.

Any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: Local install or elsewhere?